# Comparing two zipped lists

Tags: python, list, zip, comparison

I have two zipped lists of (value, associated label) where label is an integer and want to check whether they are the same; how would I do that?

Comment: @BhargavRao, does that work for zipped lists, though?

Comment: Yes, Certainly. Try it and check. If it works, inform me.